# How to call jquery dialog on gridview button click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using [jquerydialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).I have a gridview and an edit button in it.I want to call the `jquery dialog` on gridview edit buttons `click event` and .How can i achieve this?JqueryDialog is working properly on a button click event when is placed outside the gridview

Here the javascript

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(function() {    
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            show:{
                effect:"blind",
                duration:1000                
            },
            hide:{
                effect:"explode",
                duration:1000
            },
            height:500,
            width:550,
            modal:true              
        });            
   });
   $("input[id$=btnAdd]").live("click",function(){                
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        });
 </script>
```

Heres the gridview i have used

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdProgram" runat="server" CssClass="ui-widget ui-widget-contain" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="700px"
HeaderStyle-CssClass="ui-widget-header">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SlNo">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# "Test1" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text='<%# "Test2" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>           
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server" Text='<%# "Test3" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="button" id="btnEdit" runat="server" value="Edit" /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>     
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to like this.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
             <input type="button" id="btnEdit" runat="server" value="Edit" onclick="showDialog(this);" /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

in JS

```
function ShowDialog(currObj)
{
   // do some thing with currObj data
  $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            show:{
                effect:"blind",
                duration:1000                
            },
            hide:{
                effect:"explode",
                duration:1000
            },
            height:500,
            width:550,
            modal:true              
        });      
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I initially tried much of the above methods and finally struck gold.

Comment: @Ravi can we do the same for asp button?

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly....!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<%=gdProgram.ClientID%> :button').click(function(){
           $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Just in case it does not work.. It means that you have some other jquery on master page which is conflicting with this code. You just need to use `jQuery.noConflict` for that.

```
 var j=jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function(){
        j('#<%=gdProgram.ClientID%> :button').click(function(){
               j("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can specifiy button ID directly by using Jquery,     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[id$="btnEdit"]').click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });

Answer (score 0):

Using the same concept from [Tejs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148004/tejs) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203284/122005) you may try the following:

Change the gridview button to:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

And your JS call:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
         $('#<%= btnEdit.ClientID %>').click(function(e) 
         { 
             $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

             if(/*Some Condition Is Not Met*/) 
                return false;
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using class instead of Id as a selector when selecting the input type button inside the gridview.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
      <input type="button" id="btnEdit" class="btnClass" runat="server" value="Edit" /> 
    </ItemTemplate>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $(document).ready(function()
         {
            $('.btnClass').unbind("click");
            $('.btnClass').bind("click", function() {

                 $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

                 if(/*Some Condition Is Not Met*/) 
                 return false;
            });
         });
    </script>
```